# Magento 2 - Notice: Undefined variable: template in \vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer.php on line 379

Tags: magento2

I have a problem, the interface shows it.

```
1 exception(s):

Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: template in 

\vendor\magento\framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer.php on line 379
```

and in the backend it shows everything without style and with errors, for this I need to deploy static-content, but this command does not work properly, what can I do to fix it all, it all happened after I did di:compile

[image]

Comment: What happens when you deploy? Any error?

Comment: Raj Mohan R I added a picture for you to see, thanks

Comment: Try to clear /var/www/html/generated folder and clear cache. If that doesn't help - just re-deploy static content after you clear /var/www/html/generated and /var/www/html/var/view_preprocesed folders

Answer (score 0):

Try to change workflow type from **Client side less compilation** to **Server side less compilation** in **Stores -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Frontend Development Workflow**.

Possibly also remove the cache.